# Remove whitespace sequences within strings using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

HTML

```
<h3>Original String</h3>
    <pre class="original">      Paragraph of text with       multiple    white   spaces before and after.       </pre>
    <br>
 <h3>Trimmed String</h3>
 <pre class="trimmed"></pre>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myStr = $(".original").text();
        var trimStr = $.trim(myStr);
        trimStr = trimStr.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "");
        $(".trimmed").html(trimStr);
    });
```

The above code is trimming start and end of paragraph but not between. The output is:

```
Paragraph of text with       multiple    white   spaces before and after.
```

I want the output to be

```
Paragraph of text with multiple white spaces before and after.
```

Here is my JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n5t3cse1

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the `<pre>` tag instead of the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could get this done using a single line.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".trimmed").html($(".original").text().replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim())
});
```

The *regex* finds any sequential spaces and *replace()* function replaces them by a single space. Trim() is used to remove white spaces from start and end of string.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what the regex you added does.

Answer (score 1):

Replace two or more space characters with a single space by using regex.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myStr = $(".original").text();
  var trimStr = myStr.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ').trim();
  $(".trimmed").html(trimStr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Original String</h3>
<pre class="original">      Paragraph of text with       multiple    white   spaces before and after.       </pre>
<br>
<h3>Trimmed String</h3>
<pre class="trimmed"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

After trimming the string, you could replace any sequence of more than one space with a single space:

```
trimStr = trimStr.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a loop to remove the double spaces until no double space is found.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myStr = $(".original").text();
        var trimStr = $.trim(myStr);
        while(trimStr.indexOf('  ')!=-1)
          trimStr = trimStr.replace('  ', '');
        $(".trimmed").html(trimStr);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Original String</h3>
    <pre class="original">      Paragraph of text with       multiple    white   spaces before and after.       </pre>
    <br>
 <h3>Trimmed String</h3>
 <pre class="trimmed"></pre>
```